# Java 2D array is not saving the user input

Tags: java, windowbuilder

I am using a GUI and every time the user inputs the information, it won't save to the 2D array.

```java
public String [][] arrayQues = new String[2][5];

textFieldAns = new JTextField();
textFieldAns.setBounds(127, 130, 272, 42);
textFieldAns.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String Ans = textFieldAns.getText();
        textFieldAns.selectAll();
        arrayQues[1][0] = Ans;
    }
});
```

I know it does not save to the 2D array because in another class that inherits the above class, the randQ label shows up as `null`

```java
    Random r = new Random();
    int randAnswer = r.nextInt(arrayQues[1].length);
    int randQuestion = r.nextInt(arrayQues[0].length);
    String randQ = arrayQues[0][randQuestion];
    String randA = arrayQues[1][randQuestion];

    JLabel randomQuestion = new JLabel(randQ);
    randomQuestion.setBounds(112, 61, 269, frame.getContentPane().add(randomQuestion);
```

Comment: java != javascript, keep it in mind... your tags have been edited to fix this

Comment: It looks like the answer is going into the array. What led you to the. conclusion that it wasn't being copied into the array?

Comment: To help us troubleshoot the problem, will you put 'System.out.Println(Ans);' the line after 'Ans' is declared, and then tell us what it says in the comments?

Comment: I did the System.out.Println(Ans); and I got the exact input without any comments so maybe it has to do with the classes being inherited?

Answer (score 1):

create a variable to know, **at which index the next question/answer will be stored** into arrayQues.

```
private int quesIndex;
```

the in you method `actionPerformed`, call

```
String answer = textFieldAns.getText();
textFieldAns.selectAll();
arrayQues[1][quesIndex] = answer;
```

your questions should be inserted accordingly before taking the answer

```
arrayQues[0][quesIndex] = "insert your question here";
```